# Plotting a bar plot from two nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I have below two dictionaries:

```
data1 = {'value-A': {'mean': 10.0, 'count': 100},
         'value-B': {'mean': 2.0, 'count': 150},
         'value-C': {'mean': 6.6, 'count': 220},
         'value-D': {'mean': 11.4, 'count': 200}}

data2 = {'value-A': {'mean': 20.0, 'count': 50},
         'value-B': {'mean': 6.0, 'count': 100},
         'value-C': {'mean': 18.6, 'count': 150},
         'value-D': {'mean': 30.4, 'count': 120}}
```

I have below questions:

1. How can I plot a bar graph for single dictionary?
2. How can plot a comparison bar graph for mean values from two different dictionary like above? I am looking something like below snapshot
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pyplot.bar` to make a bar plot. You can check the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) for more details about it, but you need the location of the bars (in your case, the `value_x_mean` variables) and the height of the bars (`value_x_count`). I suggest renaming your parameters inside the dictionary to make iterating through it easier:

```
data = {
"value-A" : {
    "value-a-mean" : 10.0,
    "value-a-count" : 100 
},
"value-B" : {
    "value-b-mean" : 2.0,
    "value-b-count" : 150 
},
"value-C" : {
    "value-c-mean" : 6.6,
    "value-c-count" : 220 
},
"value-D" : {
    "value-d-mean" : 11.4,
    "value-d-count" : 200 
    }
} 


for key, value in data.items():
    for sub_key, sub_value in value.items():
        # When you do 'value_a_mean'.split('-') you get ['value', 'a', 'mean']
        # We take the last item from this list [-1], so just 'mean' or 'count'
        value[sub_key.split('-')[-1]] = value[sub_key]
        del value[sub_key]
```

Now `data` will look like this:

```
{
    "value-A" : {
        "mean" : 10.0,
        "count" : 100 
    },
    "value-B" : {
        "mean" : 2.0,
        "count" : 150 
    },
    "value-C" : {
        "mean" : 6.6,
        "count" : 220 
    },
    "value-D" : {
        "mean" : 11.4,
        "count" : 200 
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

data = {
    "value-A" : {
        "mean" : 10.0,
        "count" : 100 
    },
    "value-B" : {
        "mean" : 2.0,
        "count" : 150 
    },
    "value-C" : {
        "mean" : 6.6,
        "count" : 220 
    },
    "value-D" : {
        "mean" : 11.4,
        "count" : 200 
    }
} 

means, counts, labels = [], [], []

# Read the dictionary and save values
for key, value in data.items():
    labels.append(key)
    means.append(value['mean'])
    counts.append(value['count'])

# Bar plot
pyplot.bar(means, counts, tick_label=labels)
pyplot.show()
```

Result:

[image]

You can do this for as many other dictionaries as you want and the bar plots will show up together. You can use a legend to label them:

```
# Random 2nd dictionary
data2 = {
    "value-A" : {
        "mean" : 20.0,
        "count" : 100 
    },
    "value-B" : {
        "mean" : 3.0,
        "count" : 150 
    },
    "value-C" : {
        "mean" : 5.6,
        "count" : 220 
    },
    "value-D" : {
        "mean" : 8.4,
        "count" : 200 
    }
} 

means, counts, labels = [], [], []

for key, value in data.items():
    means.append(value['mean'])
    counts.append(value['count'])

pyplot.bar(means, counts, label="Dataset 1")

means, counts, labels = [], [], []

for key, value in data2.items():
    means.append(value['mean'])
    counts.append(value['count'])

pyplot.bar(means, counts, label="Dataset 2")
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Given nested dictionaries, or dictionaries in general, it is typically easier to use `pandas`, and then to plot with [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html) or [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).

  - `seaborn` is a high-level API for `matplotlib`
  - `pandas.DataFrame.plot` uses `matplotlib` as the default backend.
  - The shape of the dataframe, and the desired plot, should determine which plotting API to use.
- Also see [How to plot a bar plot from a nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76301036/7758804), which plots directly with `pandas.DataFrame.plot.`

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# create a dataframe with a unique column, data, to identify which dictionary
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d).assign(data=i) for i, d in enumerate([data1, data2], start=1)], ignore_index=False)

# reset the index to be a column and rename it
df = df.reset_index().rename({'index': 'category'}, axis=1)

# convert the dataframe to a long for to work more easily with seaborn
dfm = df.melt(id_vars=['category', 'data'])

# plot both mean and count
g = sns.catplot(data=dfm, kind='bar', x='variable', y='value', hue='data', col='category')

# plot just one category by selecting the data value for that column and then plotting
data = dfm[dfm['category'].eq('mean')]
g = sns.catplot(data=data, kind='bar', x='variable', y='value', hue='data', col='category')
```

[image]

[image]

#### `df`

```
  category  value-A  value-B  value-C  value-D  data
0     mean     10.0      2.0      6.6     11.4     1
1    count    100.0    150.0    220.0    200.0     1
2     mean     20.0      6.0     18.6     30.4     2
3    count     50.0    100.0    150.0    120.0     2
```

#### `dfm`

```
   category  data variable  value
0      mean     1  value-A   10.0
1     count     1  value-A  100.0
2      mean     2  value-A   20.0
3     count     2  value-A   50.0
4      mean     1  value-B    2.0
5     count     1  value-B  150.0
6      mean     2  value-B    6.0
7     count     2  value-B  100.0
8      mean     1  value-C    6.6
9     count     1  value-C  220.0
10     mean     2  value-C   18.6
11    count     2  value-C  150.0
12     mean     1  value-D   11.4
13    count     1  value-D  200.0
14     mean     2  value-D   30.4
15    count     2  value-D  120.0
```